# Change Awesomium proxy setting while running in C#

Tags: c#, session, proxy, awesomium

I used from this code for change proxy :

```
 WebPreferences prefs1 = new WebPreferences();
 prefs1.ProxyConfig = proxy + ":" + port;
 session = WebCore.Sessions[dataPath] ??
     WebCore.CreateWebSession(dataPath, prefs1);
```

it's work perfectly when i want to create new sessions but when i try to change proxy with this code Not WORK bcs i don't create new sessions !

i don't want create new sessions and also in current sessions i can't change proxy setting or WebPreferences .....

so i want to know how can i change WebPreferences and ProxyConfig while Awesomium running...

kind regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question was cross-posted to http://answers.awesomium.com

For the benefit of other users, I'm documenting [the cross-post's answer from Awesomium's lead developer, Perikles C. Stephanidis](http://answers.awesomium.com/questions/4196/change-awesomium-proxy-setting-while-running-in-c.html):

> As it's been discussed in many similar posts:
>
> - You cannot change WebPreferences of a WebSession after the session is created.
> - You cannot change the WebSession of a view (WebControl) after the view is created.
>     So this simply means that in order to change any of the preferences specified for a session and use them with a view, you need to create a new WebSession with the new preferences, and a new view (WebControl) that uses this new session. There is no other way.
>
> To do this programmatically using the WinForms WebControl, see:
>
> [Using Web-Sessions - Assigning to a WebControl programmatically](http://wiki.awesomium.net/general-use/using-web-sessions.html#assigning_to_a_webcontrol_programmatically)

Comment: Sidenote: Why Awesomium decided to use a private labeled clone of StackOverflow (AnswerHub) instead of just monitoring [SO questions tagged as Awesomium](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/awesomium) is beyond me.